# How to find the username who performed SSH?

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-shell, hostname, username

When one does `ssh oracle@hostB` on a local host say A, will the `hostB` know the user who performed SSH on host A?
Is there a way to find out the username who performed SSH?

Comment: Can I clarify the question? You have multiple people SSHing into a machine using `oracle@hostname`, and you want to know *which* person signed in as `oracle` at that time?

Comment: @matigo yes, you're right

Comment: No, there is no way.

Answer (score 2):

When using `ssh`, you log in to the remote computer `hostname` as one of the users know to that remote computer. Thus, anyone logging in on as user `oracle` will be known as that single user on the remote computer.

If you want to differentiate who logs in on the remote computer, then give each user his own account. Administer your system, i.e., set umasks, ownerships and permissions or use ACL extended permissions, to make sure any user can do what that user is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps:

If you set the server up so that people use public and private keys to log in (and deny passwords), the key used to log into the server is recorded in the system log files by the ssh daemon.

You can find out the matching key by running the following command on all the public keys until you find a match

```
ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/xxxx.pub
```

where xxx is the name of a public key, when the output matches the log file entry you have the identity of the user connecting to the server.

Answer (score 0):

By "host A", do you mean the host **on which** the command `ssh oracle@hostname` is performed, or the remote host `hostname`?

In the first case, obviously the name of the local user who performs the command is known to the local host. It is stored for example in environment variables `LOGNAME` or `USERNAME`, or may be obtained using the command `id -un`.

If you want to eg. record that name, you can replace the `ssh` binary with a wrapper script, that gets the local user name using any of the above methods, writes it to some logfile together with a timestamp, and then calls the "real" `ssh` binary with the original arguments provided to the script.